# Regular expression to validate version numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression to validate version numbers.

I have 4 types of version number:

- `2015.1`
- `2015.1.01`
- `2015.1.01.1`
- `2015.1.01.1.RE`
- Group 1#: I need exactly 4 numbers
- Group 2#: exactly 1 number
- Group 3#: (1-2) numbers
- Group 4#: (1-4) numbers
- Group 5#: just `RE`

I already tried `^(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\w+)$` but doesn't work.

```
string Expressao = @"^(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\w+)$";
Regex Reg = new Regex(Expressao);
foreach(string rotulo in rotulos)
{
    Match result = Reg.Match(rotulo);
    if (result.Success)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Sucesso! {0}", rotulo), ConsoleColor.Green);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Falha! {0}", rotulo), ConsoleColor.Green);
    }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex must be,

```
string Expressao = @"^\d{4}\.\d(?:\.\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,4}(?:\.RE)?)?)?$";
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xW9xW5/1)

Comment: What's the problem with the OP's regex? It should have worked.

Comment: Works perfectly !
Thank you !

Comment: @MarceloNascimento Say thanks in the form of accept,.

Comment: @AvinashRaj The answer should explain the changes you made and why they were necessary. Get detailed.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized my second version was the same as yours.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start out with the basics.

First, list the five groups

1. `[0-9]{4}`
2. `[0-9]`
3. `[0-9]{1,2}`
4. `[0-9]{1,4}`
5. `RE`

Next, list the four variations

1. `[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]`
2. `[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}`
3. `[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,4}`
4. `[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,4}\.RE`

Finally, put them all together.

`^([0-9]{4}\.[0-9]|[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,4}|[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,4}\.RE)$`

This gives an working answer, but not a very nice one.

But knowing a little RE magic, you can create a nicer version. Here I linked optionals to chain together the full version.

`^[0-9]{4}\.[0-9](\.[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,4}(\.RE)?)?)?$`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using c# then you can use [Version.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version.tryparse?view=net-6.0).

Sample:

```
string strVersion = "23.1.0";
if(Version.TryParse(strVersion, out Version version)
{
     // valid parsed.
}
else
{
    // invalid version.
}
```